# connecting the certificate in the container wordpress+apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl, docker-compose, bitnami

Need help connecting the certificate. For example, the image is ready docker wordpress bitnami. How to configure ssl for apache in container using certbot?

Docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
    services:
      mariadb:
        image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.6
        volumes:
          - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb'
        environment:
          # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
          - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
          - MARIADB_USER=bn_wordpress
          - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_wordpress
      wordpress:
        image: docker.io/bitnami/wordpress:6
        ports:
          - '80:8080'
          - '443:8443'
        volumes:
          - 'wordpress_data:/bitnami/wordpress'
        depends_on:
          - mariadb
        environment:
          # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
          - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
          - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
          - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306
          - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_USER=bn_wordpress
          - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_wordpress
```

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, it's not explicitly clear from the bitnami wordpress image docs as the link points to their apache image: https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/wordpress/README.md#customize-this-image

However, if you just add a volume as directed in the apache image you'll find it works:

```
    volumes:
  - 'wordpress_data:/bitnami/wordpress'
  - '/path/to/your/certs:/certs'.       <-- add this bit :)
```

The certs have to be named as per their apache docs: https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/apache#using-custom-ssl-certificates

> In your local computer, create a folder called certs and put your certificates files. Make sure you rename both files to server.crt and server.key respectively:

I gave it a go after reading/tracing through the Dockerfile of what I assume is the base image used by compose... I assume bitnami "genericize" their images across apps.

HTH